# How to change hbm2ddl.auto in servlet? not in xml

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I know that `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` is set in xml file. 
When I am creating a web application, first, I need to create a new table in database. So the hbm2ddl.auto should be create. Then I want to insert data into this table, and I do not want to change hbm2ddl.auto by hand. How to change this in the servlet.java to "update"?

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: You cannot.

---

Here is why: `hbm2ddl.auto` is an evironmental variable that is used in immutable `SessionFactory`. It is instantiated at the application start an it cannot be changed. I don't see why would you need to change it to `update` at the runtime. If you change the entity model in the code "by hand" you need to deploy the app anyway, so you can change the value to `update` as well. But I wouldn't trust the update option for the serious production build.

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the variable, but you can start the SchemaUpdate at Runtime. You need only the Configuration.

Use:

```
new SchemaUpdate(cfg).execute(script, doUpdate)
```

script = true -> print all DDL to the console

doUpdate = true -> changes on DB